# Fast way to identify small binary data

Tags: sql, performance, binary

I have small binary data ~200 bytes, and I can have many the data sets which must be identified with the index, so should I use just:

```
SELECT id WHERE BLOB(200bytes)
```

or it will be very slow because there will be so many rows, and are there better options?

Comment: Should this be tagged as `mysql`?

Comment: I think it related to any sql.

Comment: Are you just asking about performance? If so, I am suggesting that you include which RDBMS. (The code you posted doesn't even have `FROM tbl` so "any sql" does not really apply.)